# Add day to dateTime in query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with n records and each record has two field `startDate` and `day` and i want to select records that if i add day to startDate , result is >= DateTime.Now

can i do it with query?

Comment: what are the datatypes of the two columns? how do your values looked like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE startdate + INTERVAL day DAY >= NOW();
```

See juergen d's fiddle: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeb77/1

Comment: [Here is my Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeb77/1) in case you want to add it to your answer.